# ReactJS with Typescript: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I recently moved from .jsx to .tsx, and I'm having same issue but, I'm importing PropTypes correctly (before moving to typescript, was all working well). I suspect there's something related to typescript, but I don't know what. Anybody can help me?

```
//Board.tsx file

//Dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

//Components
import Button from '../components/Button';
import TaskCard from '../components/TaskCard';

//Data
import tasks from '../data/dataTasks';
import boards from '../data/dataBoards';

class Board extends Component<any, any>{
    static propTypes = {
        boards: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        task: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }

    render(){
        const { boards, task }:any = this.props;


        return(
            boards && boards.map(
                (boards, key) =>
                <div key={key} className="col-xs-3">
                    <div className="card">
                        <h4 className="card_title txt-secondary-color">{boards.name}</h4>
                        {
                            //Chequeo si existen tasks para cada board, sino muestro mensaje
                            tasks.filter(task => task.board == boards.id).length!=0 ?(
                            <div className="card_container_items">
                                {/* Filtro los tasks que coincidan con el board actual */}
                                <TaskCard tasks={tasks.filter(task => task.board == boards.id)}/>
                            </div>
                        ): (
                            <div className="v-padding v-margin center-align">
                                <p className="txt-tertiary-color">Aún no tenés tareas {boards.advice}.</p>
                            </div>
                            )
                        }
                        <div className="card_actions row no-margin">
                            <Button text="Nuevo" icon="+" classNameCustom="btn_primary" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        )
    }
}

export default Board;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't imported PropTypes module correctly, as it has no default export, you need to import it with `*` to access it in the same namespaced manner

```
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

If you don't have types installed you will need to add its types to your project

```
npm install -D @types/prop-types
```

Personally though I find it unnecessary to use PropTypes in a typescript project, as you should be typing your props interfaces anyway, so there are only very few situations that an actual runtime check is useful, as most issues will be caught by the compiler before it ever makes it to a browser. For example...

```
export interface IBoard {
  // your board properties type defs
}

export interface ITask {
  // task property type defs
}

export interface IBoardProps {
  boards: IBoard[]  // a required array of IBoard objects
  task: ITask // a required ITask object 
}

// the type `P` passed to `Component<P>` tells the compiler what type of `this.props` must be
class Board extends Component<IBoardProps>{
  // no need for `static propTypes` 
  // as compiler knows and checks type of supplied props
  // and also if required props are missing
  // and won't compile if they are incorrectly implemented

  render() {
    const {boards, task} = this.props // don't type these as `any`, the compiler will infer their actual type from the props
    // ... now you code is type safe from here, as types are inferred

  }
}

export default Board
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was very hard to find some explanations about typescript in react :/